# Object is not from this UnitOfWork

Tags: eclipselink

I get an error saying:

Exception [EclipseLink-6004] ... The Object bla bla is not from this UnitOfWork object space, but from the parent session's. The Object was never registered with this UnitOfWork.

This is an exception that pops up at random. Does anyone have a clue as to how to solve the issue?

thank you for your advice,
Micha

Answer (score -1):

It means you have somehow corrupted your persistence context.  Most likely by mixing detached and managed objects.

Comment: your answer is not helpful to find a solution. do you have more insight on how to prevent this? and please do not answer "avoid mixing detached and managed objects"

Comment: Came here for same problem. Can anyone explain how a persistence context can be corrupted? I get this error often but not always, and seemingly for a random pick of one single piece of data from a large collection of data (all other pieces of data get processed properly).

Comment: me too. In my case it happens when accessing lazy collections outside transactional context, after calling Stateless EJB refresh() from JSF ViewScoped beans