# UnitOfWork Exception triggered after System-Crash

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee, mariadb, unit-of-work

### Context:

The application persists objects in a `PendingJobTable`, which then get retrieved and processed. This table holds objects in their original state (before being processed).

One of the scheduled jobs runs `@Startup` to create a worker, which retrieves all the original objects to process them.

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class PendingJobExecutor {
    @EJB
    private PendingJobWorker pendingJobWorker;

    @PostConstruct
    public void startUp() {
        Logger.info("Executing pending jobs ...");
        pendingJobWorker.runPendingJobs();
    }
}
```

`PendingJobWorker` simply injects the `PendingService` and calls the `pendingService.executePendingJobs()` method:

```
@Singleton
public class PendingJobWorker {
    private final PendingService pendingService;

    @Inject
    public PendingJobWorker(
            @Pending final PendingService pendingService) {
        this.pendingService = pendingService;
    }

    public void runPendingJobs() {
        pendingService.executePendingJobs();
    }
}
```

The `PendingService` retrieves all pending jobs using `findPendingJobs`, lets the worker process them (Futures) one-by-one, and then saves the resulting objects using `saveJob`:

```
@Transactional
public abstract class JobRepositoryBase {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "Production")
    protected EntityManager entityManager;

    protected PendingJob findPendingJob(final UUID jobId) {
        return entityManager.find(PendingJob.class, jobId);
    }

    protected void saveJob(final UUID jobId, final Future<? extends Job> jobFuture) {
        try {
            // Save processed object
            final var job = jobFuture.get();
            entityManager.persist(job);
            entityManager.flush();

            Logger.info("Processed object {} persisted.", jobId);
        } catch (final InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            Logger.error(e, "Persisting the job with ID {} failed!", jobId);
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        } catch (final CancellationException e) {
            Logger.error(e, "The job with ID {} was cancelled!", jobId);
        }
    }
```

While adding entries into the `PendingJobTable` manually (QueryConsole) works after restart, simulating a crash causes the `QueryException.` To "simulate a crash", I'm stopping the docker container in the middle of the processing process. The original job is still in the `PendingJobTable` and should be processed again on `@Startup`.

Can I somehow capture the `UnitOfWork` from the parent and continue working after the "crash?"

### Exception:

```
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-6004] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.9.payara-p1): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException
Exception Description: The object [PendingJob], of class [class com.example.PendingJob], with identity hashcode (System.identityHashCod
e()) [948,982,881], is not from this UnitOfWork object space, but the parent session's. The object was never registered in this UnitOfWork, but read from the parent session and related to an object registered in the UnitOfWork.
```

### Platform Info

- Jakarta EE Platform 9.1.0
- Java 11
- MariaDB jdbc
- Payara Application Server
- plain JPA (no hibernate)

### Found "solutions"

- [Object is not from this UnitOfWork](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16428581/object-is-not-from-this-unitofwork)

### Update

The exception is caused only when I'm "crashing" docker containers using `docker-compose down`, which doesn't cause a real crash. However, the exception is not appearing (and the application works as intended) when killing or restarting the container. I will still try to find a way to fix the exception.

I kill the container (with `restart: on-failure`) using `docker ps` to find the container id:

```
docker ps
```

Then by checking what processes this container is running:

```
docker exec -it <container_id> ps -aux
```

and killing the jvm process (some pid):

```
docker exec -it <container_id> kill -9 <pid>
```